# AngularJs CoffeeScript Grunt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, requirejs

I'm facing to one problem for code optimization ie mangle. I use angular and require and everything worked fine except in service/factory case. There some examples (helloService.coffee)

```
define 'HelloService', [], ->
   'use strict'
   HS = ($timeout) ->
      sayHello: (name) ->
        $timeout ->
          console.log 'Hello: ' + name
        ,2000
   HS.$inject = ['$timeout']
   HS
```

And in controller i make something like this:(mainController.coffee)

```
define 'MainController', ['HelloService'], (HS) ->
  'use strict'
  MC = ($scope) ->
    HS.sayHello 'Stack Overflow' # it return sayHello is not a function
    # do something with scope here
  MC.$inject = ['$scope']
  MC
```

And there is how app.coffee look like:

```
define 'app', ['angular', 'HelloService', 'MainController'],(angular, HelloService, Maincontroller)->
  app = angular.module 'app', []
  app.service 'helloService', HelloService
  app.controller 'mainController', MainController

  app.bootstrap = ->
    angular.element(document).ready ->
      angular.bootstrap document, ['app']
  app
```

And somewhere (main.coffee)

```
requirejs.config
  baseUrl: ''
  paths:
    angular:['cdn_url','angular_fallback_in_project_dir']
  shim:
    angular:
       exports: 'angular'
       deps: []

require ['app'], (app) ->
  app.bootstrap()
```

This keep code easier to maintain plus it's really mimification friendly.
If i try something like:

```
hs = new HS()
```

Then i can call hs.saylHello 'String' but now $timeout is undefined or sometime is not function.

Answer (score 0):

After a long code check that's

```
define 'MainController', [], ->
   'use strict'
   MC = ($scope, HelloService) ->
       HS.sayHello 'Stack Overflow' # it return sayHello is not a function
       # do something with scope here
   MC.$inject = ['$scope', 'HelloService']
   MC
```

Instead to use require to load the service "HelloService" we give that job to angular. The reason for that choice is, internally $inject we called argument (in list) as instance using new keyword so all the property are available.
But if you will not use angular we must write it like this

```
define 'MainController', ['HelloService'], (HS) ->
   'use strict'
   MC = ($scope) ->
     HSS = new HS()
     HSS.sayHello 'Stack Overflow' # it return sayHello is not a function
     # do something with scope here
   MC.$inject = ['$scope']
   MC
```

And therefore the behavior is same. That's all.